# Multi-line strings in gradle.properties

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm developing an Android app, and I don't want to put creds under source control. I'm defining some creds in my `gradle.properties` file, like so:

```
user="bob"
pass="123"
```

I then import them in my `build.gradle` file, like so:

```
buildConfigField('String', "user", user)
resValue('string', "user", user)
```

Then, I can access them from Java as if they were a normal String resource.

Unfortunately, I also need to include a multi-line string in my `gradle.properties` file. I've tried the following:

```
long_string="this is
a multi-line string"
```

However, when I try to build my project, I get an error message that I have an unclosed string literal.

The docs for [gradle.properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html) don't seem to mention anything about multi-line string formatting.

Is what I want to do possible?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes, what you want to do is possible. You have a couple options:

You can do something like:

```
  long_string = "this is" +
      "a multi-line string"
```

Or, you can do:

```
def startingAndEndingWithANewline = '''
       line one
       line two
       line three
    '''
```

Gradle is built on Groovy, so you can just reference the [Groovy docs](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html) for things like this.

Comment: Thanks. Accepting this answer due to Groovy explanation/docs.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. The question mentions the `gradle.properties` file that has nothing to do with Groovy. I'm pretty sure this solution will not work in a `.properties` file.

Comment: Are you sure about that?

Comment: @JohnChrysostom, did you try this answer? `.properties` file is not the same as a `.gradle` file. This does not work in a `.properties` file.

Comment: Correct [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57563099/7430325) is by [Steven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10548469/steven)

Answer (score 10):

You can also do this:

```
long_string="this is a \
multi-line string \
yay"
```